# Evaluating prediction of model without having to train the model again

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data

So i've searched on the internet and in the documentation to find out i needed to save my model and reload it in another seperate file. Which i did. However, when i run my file to reload the model and predict a different input, the training start al over again. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks!

First file:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)

model.save('BTC_model')
```

Second file:

```
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.models.load_model('BTC_model')
```

Comment: so are you saying when you run model = keras.models.load_model('BTC_model') the model starts training?

Comment: yep, exactly, i just want to invoke my already trained model with the determined parameters to use the and evaluate/predict for non train data. However when i run the second file it just start training with the 25 epochs i set in the first file. Any way you know how to circumvent this??

Comment: hey, so i had the idea to delete my first file, after it saved my BTC_model in the project folder and run the second one. This time it actually did not start training and just uploaded the parameters in my new model, which is peculiar i find. You've got an idea why?

Comment: Hi! You can use model.evaluate()  to evaluate your models with sample Dataset. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate   https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/snapshot-keras/site/en/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate.ipynb